# Why python ide show blank window when there is no error warning in code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

When i  writing the code in python idle i got no error warning but there is no output as well .Can someone guide me ?Thank you

```
x=0
y=0
def add_numbers(x, y):
    return x + y

add_numbers(1, 2)
```

I expect the 3  as answer but did not  any answer only blank window.

Comment: How is this being run? If it's not in a REPL, you need to `print` something to have it show.

Comment: if you are running code as `python filename.py` you need to use `print(add_numbers(1,2))` else if you running it in Konsole or ipython it would print automaticaly

Comment: Thank you mate!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the numbers are being returned from the function - but you're not doing anything with the result. Either `print` the call:

```
print(add_numbers(1, 2))
```

Or use `print` instead of `return` and call the function as per normal:

```
  print(x + y)

add_numbers(1, 2)
```